# Push notifications about

Tags: ios, swift

Is there possible to make my swift app to send to the users notifications just one time at the same time at 21.00 clock every day?

Because something went wrong with my code:
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay

If you launch the app three times for example inside 1 minute, in the other day after 24 hours it will send three notifications, because notifications fireDate is connected with app executing.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can find good example here: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/

Comment: Thank you very much but is little bit different from my app because I unchecked the Autolayout and Size Classes, and in this program he uses them as well, and it is a little bit complicated, because I dont want so many options when notification is fired, for example remind me in 30 min. and so on. But anyway thankyou for your time showing me that link.